# Are there some signals that you cannot override their default signal handler?

Tags: linux, process, signals

This is how I think Linux signals work:

Each process have a default signal handler for each signal, some signals's default signal handler terminates the process, while other signals's default signal handler simply ignores the signal, etc.

The following table shows all the actions that a default signal handler can take (this table is from this [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)):

> **Term**   Default action is to terminate the process.
>
> **Ign**    Default action is to ignore the signal.
>
> **Core**   Default action is to terminate the process and dump core (see
>          core(5)).
>
> **Stop**   Default action is to stop the process.
>
> **Cont**   Default action is to continue the process if it is currently
>          stopped.

You can override the default signal handler with your own signal handler by using [signal()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) (which I think is deprecated) or [sigaction()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

Am I correct so far?

Now my question is: Are there some signals that you cannot override their default signal handler?

Answer (score 3):

Both man pages you linked to mention the signals whose handlers can’t be overridden. In [`signal(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught or ignored.

In  [`sigaction(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

> *signum* specifies the signal and can be any valid signal except
>          `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`.